# Python If else syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggling with If Else statement in Python 3.5.2 which I recently installed. I am using IDLE to run my code.

Here is my code below [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJOVl.png).
[image]

I get syntax error as soon as I press "Enter" key after "Else". I have tried playing with indentation, colon, etc but I am getting error on all combinations I have tried so far. I have seen similar questions (for prior version of python) here as well as on Quora but none of those solutions are working for me. Please help! (I am using MacBook - in case that changes anything).

Comment: You are typing directly into the IDLE shell and not into the IDLE editor. In the menu bar choose `IDLE -> New File` and type you code into there and then run it.

Comment: I believe he can do that, since it is just a REPL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Comment: Thanks. That actually worked when i tied into IDLE editor. Do you know why it works in editor but not in the shell? Or are we not supposed to write code in shell?

Answer (score 2):

Take the example of #3:

Python is seeing the code as

```
if x==10:
        print("X is 10")
    else:
```

The indentation on this is clearly messed up. But it looks right to you, because the `>>>` of the prompt is pushing the first line over a few characters, making it look like it is right. But even though it looks that way in the shell, python still sees `if x==10:` as being in `col 0`, and thinks that `print("X is 10")` is indented by 8 spaces and `else:` is indented by 4 spaces.

When you typed it in to the edit window, the indentation actually turned out differently, like so

```
if x==10:
        print("X is 10")
else:
```

which is actually correct (ignoring the fact that there is nothing under `else`).

Answer (score 1):

3rd example is almost the right one, but you must provide something on the `else` branch, either some code or `pass` (or just drop the `else` entirely)

**EDIT:**
After being explained the problem is with the IDLE interactive shell in specific, I tried it myself and the following code works:

[image]

This too (so the indentation seems to work on the if branch itself):

[image]

And this:

[image]

The shell automatic indentation is quiet confusing. not to say buggy.
It is clearer on plain `python` interactive mode.
The `>>>` adds a visual indentation, but there is no indentation there. The `if` body is indented by it's previous plus one, though this comes out as two indentations, it is allowed and causes no trouble.
The `else` statement needs to have the same indentation as the `if` - 0 indentation (and not one as the visalization hints). So you actually need to delete the automatically added indentation, of the `else` statement all the way back to the beginning.

Comment: He would have, but he never got a chance. The error was thrown the instant he pressed enter after typing `else`.

Comment: That's correct. I never reached a point where I could provide something to else statement as i get error before that. Interestingly, this code works in IDLE editor but not in IDLE shell. Why is that?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks. I didn't realize this is specific to the IDLE, thought it is plain python question (you may want to add tags).
Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dont indent(tab) 'else:' I think the cause is IDLE's ">>>" prompt is not aligned unlike in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.5.2 but **not** idle, this what it looks like when your code is run successfully:

```
>>> x = 8
>>> if x==10:
...   print('X is 10')
... else:
...   print('Not')
... 
Not
>>>
```

The correct form is `else:` with the colon.  This corresponds to your third attempt for which the error that see complains about indentation.  I can't see what indentation you entered but change that until you figure out what idle wants.

Comment: Thanks. One more question - I tried the third attempt code into the IDLE editor and it worked. I am not sure why this did not work when i typed into the IDLE shell.

Answer (score -2):

"elif" is a shorter way of saying "else if". if the "if" statement isnt true, "elif" can be used to tell the computer what to do if the conditions are fulfilled

Comment: This is only tangentially related to the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32419912)